# Get Item XML in SiteCore

Tags: asp.net, xml, xslt, sitecore

I'm using XSLT rendering in SiteCore.

It's being applied to an item, but it's not working. Am I able to get XML that is being used by XSLT. It will help me to found out problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some more info like "what are you trying to do, what is the error, what should it do, some code?"

Comment: Can you please provide some more details of your issue. Please explain what you're expecting and the results your getting instead. Providing sample code will help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this, but if you want to do it without coding then try this:
Go to the dbbrowser which you can find at /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx
You need to login there as admin (or user with admin rights, i think)

Then in the tree select the item you want to view the raw XML of.
After selecting, you can click on "View XML" in the right column and the XML will be displayed in the little textbox there.
You will need to copy/paste it from there to a text-editor.

Answer (score 4):

If you're after dumping out the XML of an item to the screen you can use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$sc_currentitem" />
```

.. you will probably need to 'view-source' in your browser to see the output.

Comment: This is the trick I usually use, thought I put a <textarea></textarea> around it, so it doesn't completely ruin the page